# how to test a table is already created or not in mysql database using java-servlet?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I want to know how can we check that a table is already created or not while we are dealing with databases using java .

**example :**

```
if( table exits )
{
      do something;
}
else {
       do something;
}
```

Edited version :
here is code that i tried in jsp 
but im getting some exception at "rs1=pt.executeQuery();" line

```
     <%  
       PreparedStatement pt=con.prepareStatement("select * from test");
       ResultSet rs1=null;

               rs1=pt.executeQuery();
      int count=0;
      while(rs1.next())
      count++;

      if(count>0)
      {
        //table exists
      %>
     <script type="text/javascript">

     alert("see table present");
     </script>
     <%
      }
     else
      {
      %>
       <script type="text/javascript">

      alert("see table not present");
      </script>
     <%

      }     

   %>
```

error : this is error im getting
                org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /sem-duration.jsp at line 80

```
     77:            PreparedStatement pt=con.prepareStatement("select * from test");
     78:            ResultSet rs1=null;
     79:            
     80:                    rs1=pt.executeQuery();
     81:           int count=0;
     82:           while(rs1.next())
     83:           count++;
```

Comment: why can't you write a query?

Comment: i am new to database+java , can give some example here.. ?

Comment: @SrinivasThanneeru You can't communicate with db directly, you need to communicate with db using queries. I have posted the query for checking whether the db exist.

Answer (score 3):

when you creating table using jdbc then you must be using preparedstatement something like this

```
PreparedStatement pt=connection.prepareStatement("create table test (id int);");
```

now to execute it you are using `pt.executeUpdate()` and `pt.executeUpdate()` returns `int`
  now check

```
if(pt.executeUpdate()>0)
 {
//table created
}
else
{
//not
}
```

Suppose you are not creating table using jdbc and you are just testing whether table exists or not then you can try below

```
   PreparedStatement pt=connection.prepareStatement("SELECT *
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'databasename'
AND table_name = 'tablename'");
ResultSet rs=pt.executeQuery();
int count=0;
while(rs.next())
count++;
}
if(count>0)
{
//table exists
}
else
{
//table does not exist
}
```

the other way is using databasemeta data in this following way

```
DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData(); 
    ResultSet res = meta.getTables(null, null, tableName, null); 
    while(res.next()
{
//table exists
}
```

Comment: its giving some exception like this :     org.apache.jasper.JasperException:                                An exception occurred processing JSP page /sem-duration.jsp at line 80

77:            PreparedStatement pt=con.prepareStatement("select * from test");
78:            ResultSet rs1=null;
79:            
80:                    rs1=pt.executeQuery();

Comment: @SrinivasThanneeru can you show me the code?

Comment: sir see i have give my code in the updated version my question.

Comment: @SrinivasThanneeru you have already accepted Dileep answer,post the error also

Comment: see i have given error too..

Answer (score 0):

**This will do i think.**

```
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tablename)
BEGIN
// write the codes here
END
```

*You can also do it by executing this, if you just want to check.*

```
SELECT 1 FROM tablename ;
```

this will return 0 rows if no table exist else it will greater than zero.

Comment: see i want to do some java operations depending on whether table exits or not. here your giving some db operations. can give for java ?

Comment: @SrinivasThanneeru Hope the edits solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check whether a table exists, you can run:

```
SHOW TABLES like 'your_table_name';
```

The result set will be empty if the table does not exist (check in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html) for more details).

Since you're in a servlet, you'll need to pass this query to a JDBC (Prepared)Statement.